# Display Full/Editable Grid within Relationship in Channel Form?

Tags: relationships, channel-form, grid

Using {field:grid_name} in Channel Form displays full grid with all fields.  But I was wondering if there's a way to display the Grid which is located within relationship?

For example:

```
{relationship_field}
        {field:grid_name}
{/relationship_field}
```

Something like that?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you can't do this, because when updating an entry only the *parent* entry can be saved. You'd need to do something like have a link to open up a second Channel Form - say in a pop-up or overlay - which is for the *child* entry, and then make your edits there.